# How to configure CORS on AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am days researching how CORS works on AWS S3 but I can’t configure it at all.

I need my files to NOT be publicly accessible, BUT they can be incorporated into my domains. Currently I am unable to incorporate my images into my domains, access to them is completely blocked, as if CORS did not exist.

#### AWS Block Public Access

[image: AWS Block Public Access]

#### CORS settings

```
[
  {
    "AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
    "AllowedMethods": ["GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE"],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "https://www.dev.seedlix.com.br/",
      "https://dev.seedlix.com.br/",
      "http://www.dev.seedlix.com.br/",
      "http://dev.seedlix.com.br/",
      "https://www.seedlix.com.br/",
      "https://seedlix.com.br/",
      "http://www.seedlix.com.br/",
      "http://seedlix.com.br/",
      "http://localhost:3000/",
      "52.95.163.31:443"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Looks like you are confusing two different concepts. If your files aren't publicly accessible, then you cannot access them publicly. Files that aren't publicly accessible in S3 are often retrieved with an authenticated API call from a backend and then served by that backend server.

Answer (score 2):

**After many hours of research, I finally managed to do what I wanted. First of all, I left all Bucket Accessible, and then I created a Policy that blocks access to EVERYONE except for requests originating from my domains.**

### Bucket Public Access

[image: Bucket Public Access]

### Bucket Policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "http referer policy example",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow get requests originating custom domains.",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME_HERE/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:Referer": [
            "https://domain-a.com.br/*",
            "https://domain-b.com/*",
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

### Bucket Cors Policy

[image: Bucket Cors Policy]